# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"name"' can't be used to index type 'Object'

Tags: angular

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"name"' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
`this.resto.getCurrentResto(this.router.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe((result)=> { this.editResto.controls['name'].setValue(result['name']); this.editResto.controls['location'].setValue(result['location']); })`

Comment: Is this angular 14? Maybe you can access it directly with `this.editResto.controls.name`?

Comment: I'm using Angular 13 and i also use like this it's giving me error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyword is **implicitly**. Typescript wants you to be **explicit** about using `any`.

```js
this.resto.getCurrentResto(this.router.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe((result: any)=> { ... }
```

You will have to do the same for `this.editResto.controls` if you have not defined a type for it.